# Using center alignment in HTML for e-mail

Tags: css, html, alignment, center

I started writing html for e-mails using tables. Now, for first time I tried to write using `div`s, but this is causing a problem: I cannot center align everything I used to be able to center.

Maby what I wrote is not correct, but this is only way that I find, to be able after writing to copy everything from browser to Gmail.

Can someone to tell me how I can center align in this code?

If someone can also tell me if there are better ways to write this code I would be happy to recieve criticism and helpful information.

P.S: I tried padding, positioning, margin, put height and width, but with these options in most results HALF of my bacground or my background is going off at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>

 <style type="text/css">
div#Container {
width: 895px;
height: 525px;
position: absolute;
left: 9px;
top: 15px;
}

div#Room {
padding-left: 245px;
padding-top: 80px;
width: 625px;
}

#Room span {
font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 23px;
color: #522405;
}

#D { padding-left: 70px;
}

#GD { padding-left: 103px;
}

#GPV { padding-left: 53px;
}

div#Content {
padding-left: 245px;
padding-top: 10px;
width: 625px;
}

#Right {
position: absolute;
left: 872px;
top: 222px;
}

img.Spacer {
margin-left: 10px;
}

div.content {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: black;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.BP {
vertical-align: text-top;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 245px;
}

.table {
vertical-align: text-top;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
color: #002b55;
margin-left:245px;
}

.TD {
margin-left: 30px;
}

.adress {
    font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
font-size: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #100073; 
}

.OOT {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #100073;
text-align:center;
}

.res {
vertical-align: top;
padding-left: 25px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>

<img style="position: relative;" src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/BK_zpsa93ab347.png" alt="Background" />

</div>

<div id="Container">

<div id="Room" >

    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Deluxe" target="_blank" >

    <img src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/D_zpsf4ea5de8.jpg" border="0px" alt="Deluxe" />

    </a>

    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Grand Deluxe" target="_blank" >

    <img class="Spacer" src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/GD_zpse78278b7.jpg" border="0px" alt="Grand Deluxe" />

    </a>


    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Grand Pool Villa" target="_blank" >

    <img class="Spacer" src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/GPV_zpsb381cd33.jpg" border="0px" alt="Grand Pool Villa" />

    </a>

    <br />

    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Deluxe" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span id="D">Deluxe</span></a>
    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Grand Deluxe" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span id="GD">Grand Deluxe</span></a> 
    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Grand Pool Villa" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span id="GPV">Grand Pool Villa</span></a>
  </div>

  <div id="Content" class="content">Situated on a hill, Ayara Kamala offers a beautiful garden and ocean view rooms. The place of the hotel provides quiet, calm and romantic holiday away from all other hotels on Kamala Beach.
<br />
<br />

Big size of rooms, king size beds and impressive bathrooms, are making Ayara Kamala            perfect selection for couples who are looking for privacy and relaxing holiday.
 </div>

<table class="table" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1px;" width="625" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td align="right" style="padding-left: 20px;" width="302"><a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Book Now !"><img src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/BP_zps15c948a1.png" border="0px" alt="Best Rate"/></a></td>
 <td width="321" valign="top"><table class="TD" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0px;" border="0px">
 <tr>
 <td height="30" class="res" align="center"><a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="B2B Online Booking"><span>www.b2b.onlyonetour.com</span></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="res" height="30" align="center"><span>Tel : (66) 02 - 688 - 8883 </span>      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="res" height="30" align="center"><a href="mailto:rsvn@onlyonetour.com" title="E-mail Reservation"><span>rsvn@onlyonetour.com</span></a></td>
</tr></table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div align="center" id="Right"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Only One Tour &amp; Travel Group Co., Ltd." target="_blank"><img width="149px" height="90px" src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/logoOOT_zps24c21653.png" border="0px" alt="Logo" /></a>
<a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Only One Tour &amp; Travel Group Co., Ltd." target="_blank"><span class="OOT">Only One Tour &amp; Travel<br />Group Co., Ltd.</span></a><br /><br />
<a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://on.fb.me/XXqq56" title="Only One Tour Facebook Page" target="_blank"> <img src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/facebook-logo-png-format-i18_zps83b6a9aa.png" width="145px" height="50px" border="0px" alt="FB"/></a><br /><br />
 <span class="adress">2128/9-11 Charoenkung Rd.,</span><br />
 <span class="adress">Watprayakrai, Bangkorleam,</span><br />
 <span class="adress">10120 Bangkok, Thailand.</span><br />
<a class="adress"  href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" target="_blank">www.b2b.onlyonetour.com</a><br />
<a class="adress" href="http://on.fb.me/XXqq56" target="_blank">www.onlyonetour.com (offline)</a>
 </div>

</div>

</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: First of all - why using so much `position: absolute`? If you want to center your `div#Content` remove `position: absolute` and set `margin: auto`. If you need `position: absolute` set `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -447px` (half of your container's width).

Comment: i Think you mean my div#Cntainer, not div#Content. Anyway it's because i want this div to stay over my Image div for background. If you have any other, suggestion how to make it please let me know. This that you write me doesn't help me at all...

Comment: Whatever `div` you want to center you can do it either by setting `width` in `px` or `%` or - if it is taken out of normal flow (like `position: absolute`) - by setting `left: 50%` and negative margin like: `margin-left: -(halfOfContainerWidth)px`.

Comment: it's not about center, i use absolute because i want my #Container to be over <div><img></div, i don't know why you don't understand what i am saying...

Comment: Maybe because you wrote: "Can someone to tell me how I can center align in this code?" and now you say it's not about center? :)

Comment: i already get solution, for this think, as you can read by 2'nd answer now i have another problems after this. And you ask me "why usingso much position: absolute" and i am giving you answer. Mby when you answer to something, will be better to read what he has written as a code ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now add `<div align="center"></div>` only for `newsletter`

**as like this**

```
<div align="center">

<img style="position: relative;" src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/BK_zpsa93ab347.png" alt="Background" />

</div>

<div id="Container" align="center">

// your code
</div>
```

Comment: @RohidAzad Thank YOU!, but now another problem. I just realised that when i send it as a  e-mail everything that is over my Background image is going on the bottom of the image. The other problem is after make align center, when i copy to the e-mail already my #Room, #content, table and #Right start from "K" letter of "Ayara Kamala" (name in my Background). I tryed to make only background div center and #container align-left or not aligned, but still same...

Comment: @DobriyanPetkov now define your child div text-algn:left as like this <div id="Room" style="text-align:left;"> in your inner div or table .......

Comment: i change everything to Left, and still same. In my browser looks ok, but when i move it to g-mail it's still not correct, and the other problem is when i send it as a e-mail, on the recieved e-mail everythin in #Container stays already undar my image that i would like to use as a background.... if it's not possible with divs i thi i should go back to tables, because sooooooo many problems now. I know that mistake is with me i want to learn, but from 2 days cannot make it the way it should be. I am sorry if i am annoying.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <style type="text/css">
body{
    background: url(http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/BK_zpsa93ab347.png) no-repeat top#FFF;

}
#wrapper
{
    width:950px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
}


div#Container {
width: 895px;
height: 525px;
position: absolute;
left: 9px;
top: 15px;
}

div#Room {
padding-left: 410px;
padding-top: 80px;
width: 625px;
}

#Room span {
font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 23px;
color: #522405;
}

#D { padding-left: 70px;
}

#GD { padding-left: 103px;
}

#GPV { padding-left: 53px;
}

div#Content {
padding-left: 410px;
padding-top: 10px;
width: 625px;
}

#Right {
position: absolute;
left:1030px;
top: 222px;
}

img.Spacer {
margin-left: 10px;
}

div.content {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: black;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.BP {
vertical-align: text-top;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-left: 410px;
}

.table {
vertical-align: text-top;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
color: #002b55;
padding-left: 410px;
}

.TD {
margin-left: 30px;
}

.adress {
    font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
font-size: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #100073; 
}

.OOT {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #100073;
text-align:center;
}

.res {
vertical-align: top;
padding-left: 25px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="Container">

<div id="Room" >

    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Deluxe" target="_blank" >

    <img src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/D_zpsf4ea5de8.jpg" border="0px" alt="Deluxe" />

    </a>

    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Grand Deluxe" target="_blank" >

    <img class="Spacer" src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/GD_zpse78278b7.jpg" border="0px" alt="Grand Deluxe" />

    </a>


    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Grand Pool Villa" target="_blank" >

    <img class="Spacer" src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/GPV_zpsb381cd33.jpg" border="0px" alt="Grand Pool Villa" />

    </a>

    <br />

    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Deluxe" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span id="D">Deluxe</span></a>
    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Grand Deluxe" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span id="GD">Grand Deluxe</span></a> 
    <a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Grand Pool Villa" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><span id="GPV">Grand Pool Villa</span></a>
  </div>

  <div id="Content" class="content">Situated on a hill, Ayara Kamala offers a beautiful garden and ocean view rooms. The place of the hotel provides quiet, calm and romantic holiday away from all other hotels on Kamala Beach.
<br />
<br />

Big size of rooms, king size beds and impressive bathrooms, are making Ayara Kamala            perfect selection for couples who are looking for privacy and relaxing holiday.
 </div>

<table class="table" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1px;" width="625" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td align="right" style="padding-left: 20px;" width="302"><a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Book Now !"><img src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/BP_zps15c948a1.png" border="0px" alt="Best Rate"/></a></td>
 <td width="321" valign="top"><table class="TD" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0px;" border="0px">
 <tr>
 <td height="30" class="res" align="center"><a href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="B2B Online Booking"><span>www.b2b.onlyonetour.com</span></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="res" height="30" align="center"><span>Tel : (66) 02 - 688 - 8883 </span>      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="res" height="30" align="center"><a href="mailto:rsvn@onlyonetour.com" title="E-mail Reservation"><span>rsvn@onlyonetour.com</span></a></td>
</tr></table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div align="center" id="Right"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Only One Tour &amp; Travel Group Co., Ltd." target="_blank"><img width="149px" height="90px" src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/logoOOT_zps24c21653.png" border="0px" alt="Logo" /></a>
<a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" title="Only One Tour &amp; Travel Group Co., Ltd." target="_blank"><span class="OOT">Only One Tour &amp; Travel<br />Group Co., Ltd.</span></a><br /><br />
<a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://on.fb.me/XXqq56" title="Only One Tour Facebook Page" target="_blank"> <img src="http://i1300.photobucket.com/albums/ag93/dobriyan/E-mail%20-%20Ayara%20Kamala/facebook-logo-png-format-i18_zps83b6a9aa.png" width="145px" height="50px" border="0px" alt="FB"/></a><br /><br />
 <span class="adress">2128/9-11 Charoenkung Rd.,</span><br />
 <span class="adress">Watprayakrai, Bangkorleam,</span><br />
 <span class="adress">10120 Bangkok, Thailand.</span><br />
<a class="adress"  href="http://bit.ly/XSyPG5" target="_blank">www.b2b.onlyonetour.com</a><br />
<a class="adress" href="http://on.fb.me/XXqq56" target="_blank">www.onlyonetour.com (offline)</a>
 </div>

</div>
</div>
</body> 

</html>
```

i changes your code and make it center alignment.for using div first u have set the main id(div which named as warapper) and set the margin as margin:0px auto; which automatically align your page center to all browsers

Comment: Thank You for answer ! But i am not using body background because i can not take the layout from my browser and to put it inside the e-mail. I would like to use this html code for newsletter. And your alignment for #Room, #Content, <table> and #Right is not same as i need it(it's ok i can fix the padding) but still it's not working for me the way i need it.

Answer (score 0):

Give the container the whole width of the page by setting `width: 100%;`, then set the margins of the div you want centered to auto:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: If the container is a block element, and most probably it is, there's no point in setting it's `width` to `100%`, unless it's taken out from normal flow.